# Configuring Google Chrome Cookie Exceptions

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I would like to set cookie exceptions in Google Chrome but I don't know how to avoid several entries for similar domain as in:

- `[*.]amazon.com`
- `[*.]amazon.co.uk`
- `[*.]amazon.co.jp`
- `[*.]amazon.de`
- ...

Upper configuration of course works, but it means I have to add several entries to just cover amazon sites.

**Is it possible to configure these with a single entry?**

Comment: Have you tried `[*.]amazon.[*]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can't be done in Google Chrome. [Information](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3123708?p=settings_manage_exceptions&rd=1)

This is for security reasons. Where `[*.]amazon.com` will always be a subdomain of `Amazon.com`, and therefore a site you trust, allowing all TLD's would allow anyone to create a similar site they have full control of and potentially use in a malicious way. In fact, using amazon as an example, there are some, admittedly unlikely, options still available with various [TLDs](https://www.godaddy.com/domains/searchresults.aspx?checkAvail=1&domainToCheck=amazon)

Someone with a spare $1300 who fancies making something malicious out of `amazon.yoga` would then get past your mask, and would have nothing to do with Amazon.

If you try and add a wildcard at the end, it'll revert to allowing all sites cookie access (Which is odd behaviour but it won't allow it).